# WooCommerce global.js doesn't work after update cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I write personnal javascript in **global.js**, and it work until I click on the WooCommerce button **update_cart**.

After my function doesn't work.

The function is for update notification display :

```
    $('#nb_article').change(function() {
        if ($('#nb_article').text() = 0) {
            $('#nb_article').css("display", "none");
        } else {
            $('#nb_article').css("display", "block");
        }
    });
```

and it's in balise `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {}`.

Do you know what can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update cart action is triggered on `woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/cart.js`, look for `update_cart: function() {`

It makes a ajax call to the url of form and then update the .woocommerce div with the html returned by ajax call. So, it doesn't work maybe because $('#nb_article') is inside .woocommerce and the plugin will replace all html, losing the events. You should reapply the event handler after update.

Or in alternative, you can apply the event by delegation, in this way:

```js
$('.woocommerce').on( 'change', '#nb_article', function() {
    var $nb_article = $(this);

    if ( $nb_article.text() == 0) {
        $nb_article.css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $nb_article.css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. inside event function, you have to use `$(this)` so you can refer to element that triggers the event
2. in the if statement you have to use the compare operator `==` instead of `=`

So the final results should be:

```js
$('#nb_article').change(function() {
    var $nb_article = $(this);

    if ( $nb_article.text() == 0) {
        $nb_article.css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $nb_article.css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

They are surely issues, but I don't know if there is something other related to other code of your project.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Antonino. Do you know where can I find the event of `update_cart button ? I search since two hours and I don't know where is it...

Comment: I answered you with another answer, I couldn't answer here.

Comment: Ah ok, no problem but than you for the other question ;-)